# DatagGrip does not recognize Redshift specific commands

Tags: amazon-redshift, datagrip

I'm trying to run Redshift UNLOAD command in DataGrip and it will not work. Datagrip highlights the UNLOAD keyword and the message displayed is:

```
<statement> expected, got UNLOAD.
```

It will not run.

Regular SQL statements run against Redshift though.

I'm using the Redshift JDBC driver.

Am I missing a setting somewhere or is there a specific way of running UNLOAD in DatagRip?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "will not run"?

Answer (score 0):

Talked to people at DataGrip, they do not support the redshift sql dialect at this time. Boo.

Answer (score 0):

I use DataGrip for my Redshift work almost exclusively (and have done since it was 0xDBE).

It works totally fine, especially with the Redshift JDBC driver (set the class to `com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.driver` and the dialect to `PostgreSQL`) .

If something doesn't want to run then just highlight the whole SQL statement and hit ⌘+⏎ and it sends the query unmodified. But, as of 2016.3, I'm not getting these syntax errors.

Comment: Yep, I use them every single day. 

Comment: Odd, I spoke with DataGrip support and they told it does not work and I did try using those commands and they do not work. What version are you using? I'm using the latest trial version. Did it work for you out of the box, no additional config or settings changes needed?

Comment: Ha, I've seen them say that on the forum and I always laugh because I use it for Redshift all day, every day. I've been using it for 18 months so it's hard to say what settings I may have changed. But I just tested an `UNLOAD` in a new connection on their generic Postgres driver and that works as well. If you want to DM me on Twitter (@joeharris76) maybe I can figure out why you're having issues.